# Clone User Permissions for Another User

Tags: permissions, wss-3.0, stsadm, user-accounts

I have a user that has access highly sensitive information. He is giving a meeting and we want him to use an account that has the exact same permissions as another user. I seem to remember there was a method using `STSADM` to clone the permissions from one user to another. Does anyone have an idea how to do this? The system is WSS 3.0, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are third party tools that do this but I don't know of anything out of the box.  I think the stsadm command you are remembering is migrateuser, which is for changing someone's login name for the entire farm.  As in, it doesn't clone, it replaces.

Comment: You are right. That is exactly what I was thinking of... Maybe I will have to write a PowerShell script that will do this for WSS. Thanks!